# Cannot upload password protected docx to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Recently, I find on the newly set up Sharepoint 2013 platform, I failed to upload an already password protected Microsoft document. The error is like below.(The file name is actually password.docx)

[image]

What settings can I change to solve this issue?

Comment: How big is the file? When you remove password and upload it, does the same file upload fine?

Comment: It is small only with a few words. After I remove the password, the docx can be uploaded successfully.

Comment: On your system, can you us [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f81855ef-d77d-4cee-8211-bf41cfc9e00d/sharepoint-2013-when-we-edit-a-document-we-loose-the-metadata?forum=sharepointgeneral) and [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_integration__sharepoint/2014/02/06/office-2010-error-during-check-in-of-password-protected-files-to-sharepoint/) technet articles to change `OpenXMLEncryptProperty` registry key?

Comment: The registry key should be changed on SharePoint server or the client PC on which I do uploading ?

Comment: Start with Client PC and try uploading again. Just make sure that after the registry change is done, close all office application. Open your password file. Save it. Close it. Close Word. Upload file again.

Comment: I tried but still the same error

Comment: Does your SharePoint log files give you an indication what's wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131105/discussion-between-harryquake-and-zedfoxus).

Answer (score 1):

According to this [TechNet article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_integration__sharepoint/2014/02/06/office-2010-error-during-check-in-of-password-protected-files-to-sharepoint/):

> By default, when you encrypt a file using password protection, the file properties, or metadata, are also encrypted. When the file properties are encrypted, SharePoint cannot read the existing properties, and therefore cannot write new property values to the document in SharePoint.

The solution is to not encrypt the metadata, to do this you have to change a registry key :

> 1. Open the Registry Editor by going Start > Run and typing regedit, or run it from the Command Prompt by going to Start > Programs > Accessories > Command Prompt
> 2. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Security
> 3. If you get to Common and the Security key does not exist, create it by right-clicking on Common and selecting New > Key and name it Security
> 4. Inside the Security key, create a new DWORD value by right-clicking and selecting New > DWORD (32-bit) value and name it OpenXMLEncryptProperty
> 5. Right-click OpenXMLEncryptProperty, select Modify, and in Value Data, enter the number 0, and click OK.
> 6. Close all Office applications and then test to see if the issue is resolved

and then encrypt again the problematic file from a clean copy and try to upload it.